# Running async functions in sequence with RxJS

Tags: ecmascript-6, rxjs

I'm new to RxJS and I'm having trouble getting my head around it to be honest. So thought I'd ask here and hopefully someone can push me in the right direction.

I'm creating a service that needs to expose a method that makes 2 async http rest calls, the 2nd rest call requires the output of the first. I will return a promise from the service method.

So a suedo representation would look something like this

```
export class Service {

      isAuthenticated() {
        return new Priomise<any>(resolve => { 
          this.http.post('url')
           .done((result) => {
             this.http.post('url2', { param: data.param })
               .done((result2) => {
                 resolve(result2.json());
               })
           })
       });
  }  
}
```

Any ideas what is the best way to achieve this?

Maybe I need to use the toPromise() operator? Does this unsubscribe to the Observable?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to return Promise from your function then it's better to use promises. You will not benefit from Rx in this case.

Also, I clearly see two anti patterns in your code. [Deferred for no reason and using promises as callbacks](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns)

So using Promise your code could look like this:

```js
function getFirstUser() {
  return fetch('https://api.github.com/users') // get list of all users
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(users => users[0]['login'])
    .then(username =>
      // fetch details of the first user, using his username(login)
      fetch('https://api.github.com/users/' + username)
    )
    .then(response => response.json());
}

getFirstUser()
  .then(
    user => console.log(user),
    e => console.log('got an error')
  );
```

And RxJS version:

```js
function getFirstUser() {
  return Rx.Observable.ajax('https://api.github.com/users')
    .map(res => res.response)
    .map(users => users[0]['login'])
    .switchMap(username =>
      Rx.Observable.ajax('https://api.github.com/users/' + username)
    )
    .map(res => res.response);
}

getFirstUser()
  .subscribe(
    user => console.log(user),
    error => console.log('got an error'),
    () => console.log('completed')
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice - that makes sense and has helped me!